# Applications of zero sets in topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

We call a subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ a [*zero set*](https://planetmath.org/zerosetofatopologicalspace) if it is of the form $$f^{-1}(0)\equiv\{x\in X:f(x)=0\}$$ for some continuous map $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$.

What applications do zero sets have in topology?

I know that my question seems more general but it would be good if someone can refer me to some references, like books or a thesis or a research paper. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Every zero set is closed. Presumably spaces where all closed sets are zero sets are what counts as "nice enough" for some results.

Comment: @Arthur, thank you. Do you know an example for such space and some nice result for that space

Comment: No. Otherwise I would've actually made an answer out of it. My comment is really pure speculation.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the book "Rings of continuous functions" (Gilman and Jerrison) to see why they're useful.. Filters of zerosets correspond to ideals of the ring $C(X)$.

Comment: Hnenno Brandsma, I know this book I was wondering if there are some recent references even papers would be okay

Comment: @Gob No, not really, they're only really used in this context and as a side thing in metrisation theorems sometimes. It's all old and classical. Nobody looks at them as such. Why are you interested?

Comment: Henno Brandsma , I was just curious to know more about this notion